# How do I open Minecraft.jar in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, gnome-terminal, minecraft, executable, jar

Please do not mark as duplicate because I have been searching so long on other posts but they don't work for me. Please give me a step by step tutorial as an answer and be VERY SPECIFIC. I am not a tech savvy and my cousin downloaded ubuntu (which I regret) so I honestly know nothing. I bought minecraft for $26 and it sucks that Ubuntu won't let me open. I need as many answers as I can get, because like I said before, I tried other users advices but none of them worked.Thank you so much.

*Also I asked to not mark as duplicate and of course TWO of you marked it as duplicate oh whale i understand

ok so i did this:

java -jar Minecraft.jar

Error: Unable to access jarfile Minecraft.jar

nvm I got Windows back :) thank you for your help and to those who say I need to write everything out, I'm really sorry but it was really late when I tried to fix it so I was trying so many things and I was so frustrated that I fell asleep on my desk.. I honestly know that I did try every answer to this question on this website.

But I'm glad that some people took time to answer and I apologize greatly that my question was "all fluff and no substance." I hope that you all have a wonderful day~

Comment: You say that other answers don't work for you - please [edit] your question and describe what you have actually done, and what happened.

Comment: A lot of fluff and no substance. Except for the last three lines which you only added after closing, this question contains no useful information. If you tried things and they didn't work, what makes you think we won't suggest the same thing again unless you tell as what you tried and what went wrong? I'm voting to leave closed until you list out *every* thing you tried and the result of all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal in the directory where `Minecraft.jar` is stored and try with the following command

```
java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

Then post the result.

Comment: This is only a half answer and doesn't explain how to get Oracle Java which Minecraft needs on the system.